# DNS and "site is offline" messages

Tags: dns

The scenario is this: suppose there is a web server that for whatever reason has stopped working. Is it possible for me to use DNS to have another server respond with a webpage with a message similar to "site is offline?" Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You simply need to get the second server up and running, and then change the DNS entries to point to the new A record for the new server.  (Or AAAA record if you have IPv6 for it as well).