# DNS servers pointing to site saying "owner knows site is down"?

Tags: dns

When my site goes down, I want to change my registrar DNS settings to 
point to (for example):

```
ns1.this_site_is_down.com
ns2.this_site_is_down.com
ns3.this_site_is_down.com
ns4.this_site_is_down.com
```

where these nameservers would return a fixed IP with a low TTL for all 
queries (or even a CNAME), and a webpage on that IP address would read 
something like:

The owner of this website knows it is down and is working to fix 
it. Once the site is fixed, you will no longer see this message.

To use this service, set your DNS servers to ... [as above]

Does such a service exist?

I realize this system wouldn't be perfect, but it would be useful.

[DNS and "site is offline" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872908/dns-and-site-is-offline-messages) 
discusses creating your own 2nd nameserver to do this, but I'm looking 
to do this with an existing service/server.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist for A records or CNAME records (the closest you can get here is using a round robin, but that doesn't solve your issue).

Your looking for a priority tag, which exists in MX only records.

I'm afraid your best option is just on the servers send out a 503 error with a HTML page as the ErrorDocument.

Comment: I'm thinking of a situation where my servers are completely down, but my registrar's site is still working fine. I want to go to the registrar site, change my name servers, hopefully to a public service somewhere that runs a never down webserver saying "barrycarter.info is down" (or whatever). I can think of how I'd write one myself (for other people), but my servers aren't stable enough.

Comment: Your best option would be to set really low TTLs then just switch on the NS side to point to a new set of servers.

Comment: OK, but is anyone providing a public service with a website that just says "$ENV{HTTP_HOST} is down" or something?